# ifstream's operator>> to detect end of line?

Tags: c++, parsing, operator-overloading, ifstream, istream

I have an irregular list where the data look like this:

```
[Number] [Number]
[Number] [Number] [Number] 
[Number] [Number] [Number] 
[Number] [Number] [Number] 
[Number] [Number] [Number] 
[...]
```

Notice that some lines have 2 numbers, some have 3 numbers. 
Currently I have my input code look like these

```
inputFile >> a >> b >> c;
```

However, I want to it ignore lines with only 2 numbers, is there a simple work around for this? (preferably without using string manipulations and conversions)

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use getline and then parse each line seprately:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string   line;
    while(std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        std::stringstream linestream(line);
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
        if (linestream >> a >> b >> c)
        {
            // Three values have been read from the line
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution I can think of is to read the file line-by-line with `std::getline`, then store each line in turn in an `std::istringstream`, then do `>> a >> b >> c` on that and check the return value.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::string line;
while(std::getline(inputFile, line))
{
      std::stringstream ss(line);
      if ( ss >> a >> b >> c)
      {
           // line has three numbers. Work with this!
      }
      else
      {
           // line does not have three numbers. Ignore this case!
      }
}
```